# Traceback Errors when installing addons. No Module Folder in Blender Foundation Folder, and addon is not showing up inside of the addons folder

Tags: add-on, error

Blender 4.0

This is the 3rd fresh install, using the installer to delete all blender files, using windows to delete all files, and manually doing it to make sure it was not corrupted. When installing XNA lara and the .gmd file importer I either get the traceback error pictured or if I manually put the files into the folder it gives me an error saying instead that there is no script found in the module folder which blender is not generating when I install. I have tried manually copying and putting in the files that it says it cant find and I get the same error. Installing the addons from blender itself from preferences works the least.

[image: Picture of error]

Comment: They've probably not been updated to cope with the API changes for version 4 of Blender. Check to see if there's a compatible version and ask the author if there's one available.

Comment: @JohnEason The Addon was updated November 8th, were the APU Changes later on?

Comment: Blender 4 was released on November 14th. Assuming the importer addon came from [here](https://github.com/theturboturnip/yk_gmd_io), there's no mention of changes for version 4 as far as I can see.

Comment: Correct that is the plugin, I messaged the developer but I haven't gotten a response back so I am just going to assume its not compatible at the moment until further notice. XNA Lara is on the same boat last update was before November 14th so I am probably just having this issue due to bad timing

Comment: If you don't need to use Blender 4, 3.6 is still the [LTS version](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-6/) so you could install that alongside version 4 and use that for the moment. I have 5 versions installed here and all run independently with their own settings. Just don't work on and save the same file with both versions 3 and 4 because you could run into compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks ill try it out today and see if it works

Comment: @JohnEason Unfortunately I am getting the exact same kind of traceback error on version 3.2 and 3.6. also asking for a module folder that doesn't exist in my Blender 3.6 and 3.2 files as well. Most of the errors are addon python scripts

Comment: I don't know python myself but it looks like a problem in the importer code or the file you're trying to import rather than within Blender itself so we can't help you here I'm afraid.

Comment: @JohnEason Issue is fixed, addon was updated to 4.0 and it works now, I now at least know what to look for when an addon is out of date at least

Comment: Good to know. I expect questions about errors with out of date addons are going to appear here quite frequently!